# Using a comparator function to sort

Tags: python, sorting, comparator

So I'm working with a few pre-existing comparators that compare certain values in two tuples and return true if the first is greater than the second, false if otherwise. Here's the code for one of them:

```
def cmpValue(subInfo1, subInfo2):
    """
    Returns True if value in (value, work) tuple subInfo1 is GREATER than
    value in (value, work) tuple in subInfo2
    """
    # TODO...
    if subInfo1[0] > subInfo2[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now, I have a dictionary that has numerous tuple entries of the type being compared above. I want to sort them all in reverse order, but I don't really understand how I would accomplish that. I was thinking something like:

```
sortedDict = sorted(subjects, key=comparator, reverse = True)
```

But I don't know what to pass into the comparator because each comparator takes two arguments (subInfo1, subInfo2). *I cannot change the comparator functions.*

Comment: Comparator functions are deprecated in Python; use key functions instead.

Comment: `if condition: return True else: return False` should be `return condition`.

Comment: Dictionaries do not preserve order. If you want a sorted dictionary you should use `OrderedDict` from the collections module.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I miss a link to the deprecation declaration of the `cmp` operator. [Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/) it is... The [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter) has an article how to convert from `cmp` to `key`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You're passing the comparator as the `key` function. You should be passing it as the `cmp`, wrapped in some kind of function that turns it into a proper comparator.

```
def make_comparator(less_than):
    def compare(x, y):
        if less_than(x, y):
            return -1
        elif less_than(y, x):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    return compare

sortedDict = sorted(subjects, cmp=make_comparator(cmpValue), reverse=True)
```

(Although actually, you should be using key functions:

```
sorted(subjects, operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

Also note that `sortedDict` will not actually be a `dict`, so the name is rather confusing.)

Comment: Also, the comparator should not return `True` or `False` but rather -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: Nice work on the wrapper function for the comparator. You might mention `functools.cmp_to_key` also.

Comment: `functools.cmp_to_key` is available for this sort of thing

Comment: Note that this is **deprecated**. See @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams or my answer in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 72):

In Python 3 there is no `cmp` argument for the `sorted` function (nor for `list.sort`).

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), the signature is now `sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)`, so you have to use a `key` function to do a custom sort. The docs suggest:

> Use `functools.cmp_to_key()` to convert an old-style *cmp* function to a *key* function.

Here's an example:

```py
>>> def compare(x, y):
...     return x[0] - y[0]
... 
>>> data = [(4, None), (3, None), (2, None), (1, None)]
>>> from functools import cmp_to_key
>>> sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(compare))
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, None), (4, None)]
```

However, your function doesn't conform to the old `cmp` function protocol either, since it returns `True` or `False`. For your specific situation you can do:

```py
>>> your_key = cmp_to_key(make_comparator(cmpValue))
>>> sorted(data, key=your_key)
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, None), (4, None)]
```

using the `make_comparator` function from [@Fred Foo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12749495/12299000).

Answer (score 5):

The [answer of @kaya3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159044/1028772) is correct. I just propose another implementation in which we can use boolean for the comparator.

```py
class YourTupleComparator(tuple):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self[0] < other[0]

sorted(subjects, key=YourTupleComparator)
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation why could we do that?

Comment: @Tengerye what do you want to know?

Comment: Your answer looks elegant. However, I have no clue why it works (such as why only `__lt__` is enough?). It does not on Python's official guide either.

Comment: @Tengerye it is kind of implied here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__ the default implementations return `NotImplemented`, upon finding that the sorting method flips the arguments using the symmetric operator... so you can implement  only `__gt__` and it would also work (after trying `key(a) < key(b)` it would attempt with `key(b) > key(a)`). But this depends on the sorting algorithm implementation, a more robust option would be using `functools.total_ordering`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how does [the answer of @Tuan Chau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074078/3293726) work. However, it may fail in complex situations.

Consider this comparison: each element is a tuple with two dimension. Element `A` is less than `B` if one of two conditions met: 1. `A[0]` is less than `B[0]`. 2. `A[0]==B[0]` and `A[1]>B[0]`. Therefore `(1, 2) < (2, 1)`, `(1, 2) < (1, 1)`.

Try the following snippets:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

class Character(tuple):
    def __le__(self, other) -> bool:
        if self[0] < other[0] or (self[0] == other[0] and self[1] >= other[1]):
            return True
        return False


def compare(x, y):
    if x[0] == y[0]:
        return y[1] - x[1]
    return x[0] - y[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2]]
    print(sorted(array, key=Character))  # [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]

    print(sorted(array, key=cmp_to_key(compare)))  # [[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1]]
```

As you can see, the result of `class Character` is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

We can now use this to sort a 2-D array:

```
A.sort(key=lambda a: (a[0], -a[1]))
```

This will sort the 2d-array by ascending order of A[0] and descending order of A[1].

Comment: This answer does not seem to be related to the question, which is about using comparator functions to sort. A key function is not a comparator function. It looks like you are trying to answer a different question [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-fields), though that question already has an answer saying the same thing so there is no need to write it again.

Comment: This answer is related to this! Now instead of comparator we can use key in Python3 which works as a comparator.

Comment: it is related yes, but does not directly answer the question: it is only a unary function of one parameter and not a binary function of both parameters.