# Sorting by multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, sorting

I am new to programming and right now i'm writing a league table in python. I would like to sort my league by first points, and if there are two teams with the same points I would like to sort them by goal difference, and if they have the same goal difference i would like to sort by name.

The first condition is pretty easy and is working by the following:

```
table.sort(reverse=True, key=Team.getPoints)
```

how do I insert the two following conditions?

Comment: You probably want to read the [Python Sorting HowTo](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/). (Actually, I'm having trouble loading it at the moment, but there's always [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GjjYVDIjFi0J:wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a))

Comment: Wow. I have exactly same task: sort teams in league)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a Python list by two criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-criteria)

Answer (score 15):

Have the `key` function return a tuple, with items in decreasing order of priority:

```
table.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda team: (Team.getPoints(team),
                                           Team.getGoalDifference(team),
                                           Team.getName(team))
```

Alternately, you could remember a factoid from algorithms 101, and make use of the fact `.sort()` is a **stable** sort, and thus doesn't change the relative order of items in a list if they compare as equal. This means you can sort three times, in increasing order of priority:

```
table.sort(reverse=True, key=Team.getName)
table.sort(reverse=True, key=Team.getGoalDifference)
table.sort(reverse=True, key=Team.getPoints)
```

This will be slower, but allows you to easily specify whether each step should be done in `reverse` or not. This can be done without multiple sorting passes using `cmp_to_key()`, but the comparator function would be nontrivial, something like:

```
def team_cmp(t1, t2):
    for key_func, reverse in [(Team.getName, True),
                              (Team.getGoalDifference, True),
                              (Team.getPoints, True)]:
        result = cmp(key_func(t1), key_func(t2))
        if reverse: result = -result;
        if result: return result
    return 0

table.sort(functools.cmp_to_key(team_cmp))
```

(Disclaimer: the above is written from memory, untested.) Emphasis is on "without multiple passes", which does not necessarily imply "faster". The overhead from the comparator function and `cmp_to_key()`, both of which are implemented in Python (as opposed to `list.sort()` and `operator.itemgetter()`, which should be part of the C core) is likely to be significant.

As an aside, you don't need to create dummy functions to pass to the `key` parameters. You can access the attribute directly, using:

```
table.sort(key=lambda t: t.points)
```

or the [`attrgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) operator wrapper:

```
table.sort(key=attrgetter('points'))
```

Comment: Isn't the first a little different from the second?  It applies `reverse=True` to the whole tuple, whereas the three-step version only applies it to the points.

Comment: @DSM It is, I was trying to make an example that you *can* change the order for the various steps, but I guess it's not obvious and confusing.

Comment: Well, couldn't you just use `*-1` to reverse a field?

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee What if it's a string?

Comment: the function names seem to imply that they're numbers (except `getName`).

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Which is my point exactly. There's a reason why `reverse=True` is there, which is that **in general** it may not be convenient to calculate the inverse of a sort key, while the sort algorithm can just do the opposite operation easily. (Unless you do something ugly with `cmp` and `cmp_to_key`.)

Answer (score 4):

Sort the list by name first, then sort again by score difference.  Python's `sort` is stable, meaning it will preserve order of elements that compare equal.

Answer (score 0):

Python sorting algorithm is [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) which, as ACEfanatic02 points out, is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sorting#Stability) which means order is preserved. [This link](http://www.hatfulofhollow.com/posts/code/timsort/index.html) has a nice visual explanation of how it works.

Comment: And thus Tim Peters has become immortalised.