# Sorting a list of list

Tags: python, sorting

So I have a list like below:

```
points = [[0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3], [5, 3]]
```

I have been using

```
points.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[0])
```

to sort the list. But this only sorts it by first value without looking at the second value.

The result of this code is as below:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3], [5, 3], [5, 3]]
```

However, I want to sort is such that the result is:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 3], [5, 3], [5, 3]]
```

How do I do it?

Also, while we are at it, how do i remove the duplicates from this list? The final result should be like:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 3], [5, 3]]
```

Comment: No sort key at all will sort the pairs lexicographically: `points.sort()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python already sorts iterable containers (tuples, lists, ...) and strings lexicographically.

```
>>> points = [[0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3], [5, 3]]
>>> sorted(points)
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 3], [5, 3], [5, 3]]
```

Comment: @NutanNepal not at all, see [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145842/python-sorting-by-multiple-criteria). I didn't get lexicographical sorting either.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a sort key that first sorts by the first element `x[0]`, and if their are ties, sort by the second element `x[1]`:

```
>>> points = [[0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3], [5, 3], [0, 4]]
>>> sorted(points, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 3], [5, 3], [5, 3]]
```

If you don't want any duplicates in this final list, then you can do this:

```
points = [[0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3], [5, 3]]

sorted_lst = sorted(points, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

seen = set()
no_dups = []
for lst in sorted_lst:
    curr = tuple(lst)
    if curr not in seen:
        no_dups.append(lst)
        seen.add(curr)

print(no_dups)
# [[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 3], [5, 3]]
```

Which has a set `seen` which keeps track of what sublists have been added, and a list `no_dups` where the lists get added. If an element is not in `seen` and add it to the final list, and add it to `seen`, which indicates that the element has already been added.

Also since type `list` is not a hashable type, you cannot add them directly to a set. In the above code, the lists are converted to tuples and added to `seen`, which is a hashable type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to remove duplicates. That was helpful.

Comment: @NutanNepal No worries. Be sure to give it an upvote if you found helpful.

Comment: I tried to. But it says I can't upvote when I'm less than 15 rep. I was able to do it just a while ago though.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

points = [[0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 5], [0, 2], [1, 3], [5, 3]]
points.sort()
nList = list(points for points,_ in itertools.groupby(points))
print nList
```

Result:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 3], [5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try itemgetter

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(points, key=itemgetter(0, 1))
```