# How do I sort a nested list by the second value and then the first, without using packages?

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list of pairs of numbers:

```py
>>> l = [[0, 0], [1, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [5, 2], [3, 1], [1, 6], [5, 4], [4, 3], [2, 5], [3, 0]]
```

Is it possible to sort the list by the second term and then the first without using packages?
The desired output is this:

```py
>>> sort_two_then_one(l)
[[0, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [5, 2], [1, 3], [4, 3], [3, 4], [5, 4], [2, 5], [1, 6], [4, 6]]
```

Comment: What do yo mean by packages?

Comment: @DaniMesejo: like not using `operator` module.

Comment: @Hiwafreak: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

**Code**

```
lst = [[0, 0], [1, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [5, 2], [3, 1], [1, 6], [5, 4], [4, 3], [2, 5], [3, 0]]

sorted_list = sorted(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0]), key=lambda x: x[1])

print(sorted_list)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0],
 [3, 0],
 [3, 1],
 [3, 2],
 [5, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [4, 3],
 [3, 4],
 [5, 4],
 [2, 5],
 [1, 6],
 [4, 6]]
```

Comment: While this works, the list needs to be sorted twice. It is possible to sort by multiple indices in one call to `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of [Python sorting by multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145842/python-sorting-by-multiple-criteria?lq=1)

```py
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
>>> [[0, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [5, 2], [1, 3], [4, 3], [3, 4], [5, 4], [2, 5], [1, 6], [4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional key argument of `sorted()` and implement a lambda function. These are all built-in methods of python. See also [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-second-element-sublist/)

```
a=[[0, 0], [1, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [5, 2], [3, 1], [1, 6], [5, 4], [4, 3], [2, 5], [3, 0]]

print(sorted(a, key = lambda x: x[1]))
```

**output**

> [[0, 0], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [5, 2], [1, 3], [4, 3], [3, 4], [5,
>   4], [2, 5], [4, 6], [1, 6]]
>
> [Program finished]

Comment: This does not sort by the first term. Result does not equal the desired output.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke it does exactly match the desired output?

Comment: Last item should be [4,6]. Yours is [1,6]. You have to scroll to the very end. The question clearly states "by the second term and then the first". The example could have been chosen a bit more user friendly though :)

Comment: You are right!!