# Python to process the results of a PostgreSQL query to array

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql

The results of a postgres query using psycopg2 are something like this:

```
[(1, 20386, 3), (2, 20386, 5), (3, 20386, 5), (1, 20387, 2), (2, 20387, 2), (3, 20387, 3), (1, 20390, 3), (2, 20390, 3), (3, 20390, 3)]
```

I need to reorder the result such that (in PHP at least) it would look like this:

```
user['20386'][1]=3  
user['20386'][2]=5  
user['20386'][3]=5  

user['20387'][1]=2  
user['20387'][2]=2  
user['20387'][3]=3  

user['20390'][1]=3  
user['20390'][2]=3  
user['20390'][3]=3
```

Comment: This may help: [Python sorting by multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145842/python-sorting-by-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Can you post a code snippet

Comment: Obviously, the question pointed out as a duplicate has little to do with this question. Reviewers should really pay more attention when evaluating questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the data into a dict of lists:

```py
>>> user = {}
>>> for key in {item[1] for item in data}:
...     user[key] = [item[2] for item in data if item[1] == key]
```

The `user` looks like this:

```py
>>> user
{20386: [3, 5, 5], 20387: [2, 2, 3], 20390: [3, 3, 3]}
```

Note however, that lists are indexed from 0:

```py
>>> user[20386]
[3, 5, 5]
>>> user[20386][0]
3
>>> user[20386][1]
5
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I am still having difficulty wrapping my head around lists, and dict, etc. vs PHP arrays.