# sorting by multiple criteria in Python

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.8. I am trying to sort players by points (in descending order) and then, only if they have the same number of points, by rank.

I've already read [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/sorting.html), [Python sorting by multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145842/python-sorting-by-multiple-criteria) and [Sorting by multiple conditions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299448/sorting-by-multiple-conditions-in-python).

Here's my code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

players_results = [
    ("Pierre", 1.0, 1),
    ("Matthieu", 1.0, 2),
    ("Joseph", 0.5, 3),
    ("Marie", 0.0, 4),
    ("Michel", 0.5, 5),
    ("Raphael", 0.0, 6),
]

sorted_by_points = sorted(players_results, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
points_descending_rank_ascending = sorted(sorted_by_points, key=itemgetter(2))
print(points_descending_rank_ascending)

# [('Pierre', 1.0, 1), ('Matthieu', 1.0, 2), ('Joseph', 0.5, 3), ('Marie', 0.0, 4), ('Michel', 0.5, 5), ('Raphael', 0.0, 6)]
```

In each tuple, the number of points are of float type while the rank is of integer type. My problem is that Michel should be before Marie, but that's not the case. Can someone explain what I have to implement differently?

Comment: Answers on both of the SO questions you link suggest sorting on a tuple key, which you're **not** doing. You're sorting twice, not using multiple criteria simultaneously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sorting by multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145842/python-sorting-by-multiple-criteria)

Comment: " if all the other criteria are numeric, then negate their values for the sort key and add reverse=True. Otherwise, use consecutive sorts, using the rightmost criteria first, then the next, etc" Martijn Peters. What should I do if the values aren't numeric and I want to combine an ascending and a descending criteria ?

Comment: _"What should I do if the values aren't numeric..."_ - why do you ask? The values you want to sort on *are* numeric.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, but I may need it later in my project

Comment: In the absence of a concrete example, it's hard to say exactly what you should do, so you'd be better off waiting for that need to actually materialise (if it ever does) to investigate it. If you wanted some string fields to be sorted alphabetically and others reverse-alphabetically, for example, that would be quite complicated (compared to numerical fields, where it's easy to negate them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
sorted(players_results, key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[2]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[('Pierre', 1.0, 1), ('Matthieu', 1.0, 2), ('Joseph', 0.5, 3), ('Michel', 0.5, 5), ('Marie', 0.0, 4), ('Raphael', 0.0, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 3rd party libraries, such as pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

players_results = [
    ("Pierre", 1.0, 1),
    ("Matthieu", 1.0, 2),
    ("Joseph", 0.5, 3),
    ("Marie", 0.0, 4),
    ("Michel", 0.5, 5),
    ("Raphael", 0.0, 6),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(players_results)
df.columns = ["name", "points", "rank"]
df.sort_values(["points", "rank", "name"], ascending=[False, True, True])
```

[image: result]

Answer (score -1):

Attemping to respect your script, something like this works:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':

    players_results = [
        ("Pierre", 1.0, 1),
        ("Matthieu", 1.0, 2),
        ("Joseph", 0.5, 3),
        ("Marie", 0.0, 4),
        ("Michel", 0.5, 5),
        ("Raphael", 0.0, 6),
    ]


    # In one line:
    points_descending_rank_ascending = sorted(players_results, key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[2]))
    print(points_descending_rank_ascending)
```

Comment: I just wrote the script using old script. I add the simplest line.

Comment: My point is that you _didn't_ add the simplest line, and you've left one in that's totally redundant (both versions work in one line, neither requires the pre-sorting). In addition it's more helpful to write answers that explain what you've changed, why that works and why the original didn't.

Comment: I have added the simplest line, now.

Comment: Sorry, I re-edit all to be clear.