# Python sort dictionary items by value then by key

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have the following dictionary:

```
{1: (8, 3), 0: (8, 0), 2: (2, 3), 3: (2, 0)}
```

I would like to sort it by the tuple key and then by the key of the dictionary so the above will be:

```
 [{1: (2, 3), 3: (2, 0),0: (8, 3), 1: (8, 0)}]
```

I wrote the following:

```
result_list = sorted(codebook.items(), key= lambda item: item[1][0])
```

This sort by the tuple key but not afterwards by the dictionary key.

How can I do it?

Comment: Your output would be a list, not a dictionary; dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Its a little unclear what you're trying, but if you're trying to sort the dictionary, stop, it cannot be done.  Dictionaries in python are not sorted (and cannot be sorted)

Comment: Also, your sample dictionary has two keys that are the same.  This can't possibly be correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a Python list by two criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-criteria)

Comment: I fixed my question there is already a correct answer to accept i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sorted(codebook.items(), key= lambda item: (item[1][0],item[0]))
```

this will sort first by the first item in the tuple then by the dictionary key

just to clarify a few things for OP

- Dictionaries are not sortable, so you cannot ever have a "sorted" dictionary

  - (there is a OrderedDictionary, but its essentially the same as a
    NamedTuple, both of these containers do have an order)
- This will return a list of tuples not a dictionary. the return will look like

  `[(dictionary_key,(tuple,values)),(dictionary_key,(tuple,values),...]`

Comment: I'm also curious about the -1. +1 to make up for it.

Comment: I'm not the -1, but this answer doesn't produce the OP's desired result, a `list` containing one sorted `dict`. In fact, no answer possibly can.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted - to sort the dictionary

Comment: meh thats based on the authors incorrect wording of his desired solution ... I think this answers what he actually was asking

Comment: @Dejel , one cannot sort a dictionary, and that isn't what this answer does. I'm glad you found an answer the works for you, but I'm concerned that you are still confused about what this does.

Comment: but it does sort the dictionary into a list!

Comment: SortedDictionary = collections.OrderedDict