# "sort by x (ascending) then by y (descending)" for a csv file in python

Tags: python, excel, sorting, csv

So I have a csv file that I want to sort using 2 columns (basically the same idea in excel as "sort by somecol then by anothercol").

Given that csvbody is a list of lists generated from the csv file, the way I have it right now that I found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-criteria) is `sortedcsv = sorted(csvbody, key = operator.itemgetter(somecol, anothercol))` The issue is that I want to sort by somecol in ascending order and anothercol in descending order. Is there a way to do this (even better, in one line)?

I know that I could do `sortedcsv = sorted(csvbody, key = operator.itemgetter(somecol, anothercol), reverse = True)` but then it sorts both of them in descending order. Then I tried doing two lines:

```
sort1 = sorted(csvbody, key = operator.itemgetter(somecol))
sort2 = sorted(sort1, key = operator.itemgetter(anothercol), reverse = True))
```

However this doesn't work because the second sort just overrides the first sort (it's as if I went into excel and sorted in descending order just by "anothercol")

If you need me to include more information please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python's sort is guaranteed to be stable, this should do what you want:

```
# First sort by secondary key
sortedcsv = sorted(csvbody, key=operator.itemgetter(anothercol, reverse=True)
# Then sort by primary key
sortedcsv = sorted(sortedcsv, key=operator.itemgetter(somecol))
```

Reference:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts

Comment: Oh man I missed that in the docs, thanks for sharing! I probably should have tried reversing the order of the statements. I'm a little confused as to why reversing the order worked. Do you think you could point me to something that explains why it worked the second way but not the first?

Comment: In addition to the reference I list in the answer, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Comment: That card image on the right is a really good example. I understand why the second way works but not the first now (at least I believe I do! haha). Thank you very much again for the spot-on help!