# What is the right Python idiom for sorting by a single criterion (field or key)?

Tags: python, sorting, key, idioms

As in title, how can I sort objects by single criterion?

I've heard about `key` parameter, `cmp` parameter, and Decorate-Sort-Undecorate pattern.
Which one should I use in modern Python, and how?

Comment: This is my attempt to create [canonical question for sorting with key argument in Python](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314445/3821804).

Comment: Please note that even self-answered questions should meet the site's quality requirements; see [ask]. *"How to"* questions aren't a good for for SO, consider writing this up on a blog or something.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: at the moment, I really have no idea how I could improve the question, while keeping it case-agnostic; I'll think about it again tomorrow. What do you mean by *writing this up on a blog*? (English is not my first language)

Comment: I mean post this as an article on a blog, rather than trying to shoe-horn it onto SO.

Comment: I edited the title to be more specific, and voted to reopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern Python, the best way is to use `list.sort` or `sorted` with `key` argument.

When you pass `key` argument, sorting function, instead of comparing elements directly, compares whatever `key` returned for them.

So, you can pass as `key` any callable that takes element to be sorted as single positional argument, and returns what the element should be sorted by.
The callable will be called once for each element.

Some simple examples:

```
   list_ = ['B', 'aaa', 'CC']

   sorted(list_)
=> ['B', 'CC', 'aaa']

   # case-insensitive sorting
   sorted(list_, key=str.lower)
=> ['aaa', 'B', 'CC']

   # sorting by length
   sorted(list_, key=len)
=> ['B', 'CC', 'aaa']
```

Sorting with `key` is roughly equivalent to [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate pattern](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate):

```
def decorate_sort_undecorate(iterable, key):
    # 1: decorate:
    decorated = [(key(elem), index, elem) for index, elem in enumerate(iterable)]

    # 2: sort:
    decorated.sort()

    # 3: undecorate: 
    return [elem for key_, index, elem in decorated]
```

This creates temporary list (`decorated`) of 3-element tuples,
which have form: `(key_, index, elem)`, where `key_ = key(elem)`. Then, `decorated` list is sorted.
Tuples are compared by first non-equal element. This is `key_`, or if `key_`s are equal, `index`. Because there are no equal indexes, elements are never directly compared.
At the end, elements are extracted from `decorated` into new list, which is returned.

#### Random thoughts:

- Order of sorted elements can be reversed using `reverse=True`,
- [`lambda`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8966538/3821804) and functions from [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) are often passed as `key`,
- before 2.4, there were no `key` parameter. There were only [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate pattern](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate) and slow `cmp` parameter,
- [Sorting a Python list by two criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5212870/3821804).