# What does the 'sorted' function's 'key' argument do?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I input

```
print sorted([10, 4, 2, 12, 3], key=str, reverse=True)
```

Why is the result:

> [10, 12, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865217/how-can-i-sort-by-single-criterion) is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: The result is not as you say. It's `[4, 3, 2, 12, 10]`, due to the `reverse` parameter being `True`. Regardless of this, it should be trivial to find an answer to the question using the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That key sends each element to the `str` function for comparison purposes. When strings are sorted, they are compared alphabetically. Since `'1'` is before `'2'`, `'12'` comes before `'2'`, in the same way that `'and'` would come before `'ball'`. There is no such thing as place value in strings, as there is with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sorting them by their string representation, which uses lexicographical sorting: you sort by the first character, if those are the same then you compare the next one. So just like "aardvark" comes before "bee" in a dictionary, so does "10" come before "2", because the character "1" is before the character "2".