# Maximum key value from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a python dictionary with values

```
d = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 0, 'D': 4}

result = max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])

result = ('D', 4)
```

Now if there is no maximum value and all values are equal, then result should be by alphabetical order (ascending) of keys.

ie

```
 d = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 0, 'D': 1}
 result should be  D

 d = {'A': 0, 'B': 5, 'C': 5, 'D': 1}
 result should be C
```

How this can be done in Python ?

Comment: I think, your desired alphabetical ordering would be called descending...

Comment: Related? [Sorting a Python list by two criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-criteria)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the `lambda` to check the key after the value (by returning a value-key pair)

```
>>> d = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 0, 'D': 1}
>>> max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
('D', 1)
>>> d = {'A': 0, 'B': 5, 'C': 5, 'D': 1}
>>> max(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
('C', 5)
```

Comment: for explanation: a tuple is returned from the lambda, and tuples are sorted 'alphabetically' (element-wise, as strings would be character-wise)

Comment: @Ilja, `x[1]` is a value, so value is comapred first. If values of two items are equal, key(`x[0]`) is compared: `(5, 'C') > (5, 'B')`

Comment: yes, I meant this (it was not a question but a statement :)), but wrote it more abstract

Comment: Another way to write that key function: `lambda x: x[::-1]`