# Sorting a tuple of strings alphabetically and reverse alaphabetically'

Tags: python, string, sorting

Lets say you have a list of tuples (last_name, first_name) and you want to sort them reverse alphabetically by last_name and then if two people have the same name for them to be sorted alphabetically by first name. Is there a way to do this with one line?

e.g.

```
Sorted(names, key = ?) = [('Zane', 'Albert'), ('Zane', 'Bart'), ('Python', 'Alex'), ('Python', 'Monty')]
```

With two lines I guess you could rely on sort stability and first sort by first name and then sort by last name reversed.

Comment: yes... that is default sort ... you dont need anything... `sorted(names)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Not really.

Comment: i rpobably read too fast ... but `(A,B) vs (A,C)` sorts exactly how you would expect which is what it sounds like what he wants (first on last name, and in event of tie on first name)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Last name they want *descending*.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5212940/4831822)

Comment: @JoranBeasley What do you think is the negative of a *string*?

Comment: @JoranBeasley

doesn't work for strings

    `Traceback (most recent call last):File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    names2.sort(key= lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <lambda>
    names2.sort(key= lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'`

Comment: yeah i clearly didnt think that through :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `itertools.groupby` solution:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

li = [('x', 'y'), ('s', 'e'), ('s', 'a'), ('x', 'z')]

[p for k, g in groupby(sorted(li, reverse=True), itemgetter(0)) for p in reversed(list(g))]
# [('x', 'y'), ('x', 'z'), ('s', 'a'), ('s', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this with one line?
>
> With two lines I guess you could rely on sort stability and first sort by first name and then sort by last name reversed.

Well you can do exactly that in one line:

```
sorted(sorted(names, key=lambda name: name[1]), key=lambda name: name[0], reverse=True)
```

Doing two sorts for exactly this problem in the [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts) (*"to sort the student data by descending grade and then ascending age, do the age sort first and then sort again using grade"*).

---

A silly alternative doing it with just one `sorted` and `key`:

```
sorted(names, key=lambda name: ([-ord(c) for c in name[0]], name[1])) == correct
```

---

A Python 2 solution with one `sorted` and `cmp` instead of `key`:

```
sorted(names, lambda a, b: cmp(b[0], a[0]) or cmp(a, b))
```

Comment: Thanks; I was halfway to entering this when you had the job done.  My response is no longer useful, except for the [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Comment: @Seraphya Ok I just added a single-sorted solution.

Comment: @Prune Thanks, included that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rely on the stability of the sorting:

```py
names = [('Zane', 'Albert'), ('Zane', 'Bart'), ('Python', 'Alex'), ('Python', 'Monty')]

names.sort()
names.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda i: i[0])
```

Comment: FYI: Sort stability was added and Python 2.2