# Sorting two lists together in using python zip function

Tags: python, list, sorting, zip

my question is a bit different than the basic sorting two lists together.

See this code for example:

```
list1=[3,4,2,1,6,1,4,9,3,5,8]
list2=['zombie','agatha','young','old','later','world',
       'corona','nation','domain','issue','happy']
srt=sorted(list(zip(list1,list2)),reverse=True)
print(srt)
```

The output comes out to be:

```
[(9, 'nation'), (8, 'happy'), (6, 'later'), (5, 'issue'), 
 (4, 'corona'), (4, 'agatha'), (3, 'zombie'), (3, 'domain'), 
 (2, 'young'), (1, 'world'), (1, 'old')]
```

Question:- As we can see, for the values which are same in list 1, the elements of my list 2 also get sorted alphabetically in descending order. What if I want to sort the list 1 in descending order, and after that, my list 2 elements in ascending order, for which the value of elements of list 1 is same, in some trivial way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use key function `lambda k: (-k[0], k[1]))`:

```
list1 = [3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 9, 3, 5, 8]
list2 = ['zombie', 'agatha', 'young', 'old', 'later', 'world', 'corona', 'nation', 'domain', 'issue', 'happy']
srt = sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda k: (-k[0], k[1]))
print(srt)
```

Prints:

```
[(9, 'nation'), (8, 'happy'), (6, 'later'), (5, 'issue'), (4, 'agatha'), (4, 'corona'), (3, 'domain'), (3, 'zombie'), (2, 'young'), (1, 'old'), (1, 'world')]
```

Comment: `sorted` can take any iterable so you can drop `list`: `sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x, y: (-x, y))`.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Yes, good catch. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. one query, so -k[0] implies descending order for first list, and k[1] means ascending order for second list, right? Hope my intuition is correct?

Comment: @RishabhRao Yes, that's true, `-k[0]` is descending by first element, `k[1]` ascending by second element. Note: the minus sign works only for numerical data.

Comment: Oh, then how about descending for strings?

Comment: @RishabhRao That's a little bit more complicated. Look for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916223/sorting-a-tuple-of-strings-alphabetically-and-reverse-alaphabetically

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but you could do a "double" `sorted()`, first by the `list2` value then reversed `list1` value:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list1=[3,4,2,1,6,1,4,9,3,5,8]
list2=['zombie','agatha','young','old','later','world',
       'corona','nation','domain','issue','happy']


srt=sorted(sorted(zip(list1,list2), key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
print(srt)
```

Output:

```
[(9, 'nation'), (8, 'happy'), (6, 'later'), (5, 'issue'), (4, 'agatha'), (4, 'corona'), (3, 'domain'), (3, 'zombie'), (2, 'young'), (1, 'old'), (1, 'world')]
```