# convert dict of dict to dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a `dict` like this:

```
data = {'1':{'a':10, 'b':30}, '2':{'a':20, 'b':60}}
```

and I would like to convert in into a dataframe like this:

```
x   y   z
1   a   10
1   b   30
2   a   20
2   b   60
```

Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `dictionary comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in data.items()}).reset_index()
df.columns = list('xyz')

print (df)
   x  y   z
0  1  a  10
1  1  b  30
2  2  a  20
3  2  b  60
```

For better performance use `list compehension` with [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109098/2901002):

```
L = sorted([(k,k1,v1) for k,v in data.items() for k1,v1 in v.items()], 
            key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
print (L)
[('1', 'a', 10), ('1', 'b', 30), ('2', 'a', 20), ('2', 'b', 60)]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=list('xyz'))
print (df)
   x  y   z
0  1  a  10
1  1  b  30
2  2  a  20
3  2  b  60
```

**Timings**:

```
In [34]: %timeit jez1(data)
16.8 ms ± 403 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [35]: %timeit jez(data)
1.96 s ± 90.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [37]: %timeit jp(data)
43 ms ± 353 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Same code as @jp:

```
data = {str(k): {'a': 10, 'b': 30} for k in range(10000)}

def jp(data):
    return pd.melt(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'x'}),
                   id_vars=['x'], value_vars=['a', 'b'], var_name='y', value_name='z')\
             .sort_values(['x', 'y']).reset_index(drop=True)

def jez(data):
    df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in data.items()}).reset_index()
    df.columns = list('xyz')
    return df

def jez1(data):
    L = sorted([(k,k1,v1) for k,v in data.items() for k1,v1 in v.items()], key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
    df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=list('xyz'))
    return df

assert (jez1(data).values == jez(data).values).all()
```

Comment: Just saw your edit - nice one. I'd still like to *understand* the internals of why `concat` is slow. Maybe we need to start a `pandas-internal` tag!?

Comment: @jpp in my opinion reason is  to many repeatings of concat of small `Series`.

Comment: If suppose my dic is "data = {'1':{'a':10, 'b':30}, '2':{'a':20, 'b':60, 'c':30,'d' = 10}}" will the same code work??

Comment: my dic length is 2376. but when i convert it to df, the len of df is 2320. but in real case,it has to be >2376.No idea why it's missing some of the rows..

Comment: @amrutha - I test my solution with your data and working nice. How do you get length of dicts?

Comment: I try test it by `print (sum([len(v) for k, v in data.items()]))`

Comment: @amrutha - You can use `from collections import Counter` first, and then `data = {k:Counter(v) for k, v in data.items()}`, last apply first or second my solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way using `pandas.melt`.

```
d = {'1':{'a':10, 'b':30}, '2':{'a':20, 'b':60}}

res = pd.melt(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index'),
              value_vars=['a', 'b'], var_name='y', value_name='z')

print(res)

#    y   z
# 0  a  10
# 1  a  20
# 2  b  30
# 3  b  60
```

**Performance benchmarking**

I expected `pandas.melt` to be inefficient, but applying `pandas.concat` on a large number of dictionaries can be even *more* expensive.

```
data = {str(k): {'a': 10, 'b': 30} for k in range(10000)}

def jp(data):
    return pd.melt(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'x'}),
                   id_vars=['x'], value_vars=['a', 'b'], var_name='y', value_name='z')\
             .sort_values(['x', 'y']).reset_index(drop=True)

def jez(data):
    df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in data.items()}).reset_index()
    df.columns = list('xyz')
    return df

assert (jp(data).values == jez(data).values).all()

%timeit jp(data)   # 51.8 ms per loop
%timeit jez(data)  # 2.62 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Series`

```
pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
Out[359]: 
  level_0 level_1   0
0       1       a  10
1       1       b  30
2       2       a  20
3       2       b  60
```