# python sorting program that uses a dictionary to display the letters the sentence is composed of first by # of occurrence than alphabetically

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble with the sorting by alphabetical order or possibly the displaying it that way part. 
it should do this
Enter a sentence: An avocado 
a appeared 3 times

o appeared 2 times

c appeared 1 times
d appeared 1 times
n appeared 1 times
v appeared 1 times

however mine does not sort by alphabetically after the number of times.

here is my code

```
sentence = input('Enter a sentence: ')
sentence = sentence.lower()
dictionary = {}
sort = {}
for n in sentence:
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    if n.isalpha():
        if n in keys:
            dictionary[n] += 1
        else:
            dictionary[n] = 1

sort = sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda letter:letter[1], reverse = True)
print()
print('Sentence Statistics:')

for x in sort:
    if x[0].isalpha:
        print(x[0], 'appeared', x[1],'times.')
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: This specific answer is a clue https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109098/1317713

Your key should be a tuple of two elements: occurence count, then the letter itself.

Comment: Because you never ask python to sort it. You may do some magic like this
`sort = sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda letter: str(10000000-letter[1]) + letter[0])`

Comment: Note: python has `collection.Counter`, which makes these kind of problems simple, e.g. `sorted(Counter(sentence).items(), lambda letter: (letter[1], letter[0]))`

Comment: @leonid that did not work I changed the sort=... to that comment and get  this error code builtins.IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @AChampion I can not use collection.counter,  no library functions to accomplish the main goal of the problem.

Comment: @sashaaero did not work,

Comment: @Archer15 it works. Did you remove reverse as I did?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple, you just need to use a different sorting key. Use a tuple of (frequency, letter) instead of just the frequency:

```
sort = sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda letter: (letter[1], letter[0]), reverse = True)
```

Note that there's a [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the standard library that makes a lot of this even simpler.

Comment: `lambda letter: (letter[1], letter[0])` should be `lambda letter: (letter[1], -ord(letter[0]))` I think. Cause in your case letters are not sorted alphabetically.

Comment: cant use library functions, and this still does not print alphabetically ordered after numerically.

Answer (score 0):

To sort first by of occurrence then  alphabetically, you may change your sort key function to this:

```py
sort = sorted(dictionary.items(), key = lambda letter:(-letter[1], letter[0]))
```

Comment: IMO, using reverse=True produces better readable code than using negative value of the counter as key for sorted()