# What is the most efficient way to sort an array with the first item?

Tags: python, list

I want to sort the array [[x₁, y₁], [x₂, y₂], [x₃, y₃],...] by the first term. I know that it is doable with bubble sorting, but is there more concise and efficient way to sort the array? Here is a working code for bubble sorting.

```
def bubble_sort(n, array):
  for i in range(n):
    swap = False
    for j in range(n-i-1):
      if array[j][0] > array[j+1][0]:
        array[j][0], array[j+1][0] = array[j+1][0], array[j][0]
        swap = True
    if not swap:
      break
  return array
```

Comment: Sure, you can use the `sorted` function, it does the job in one line.

Comment: The default will sort by the first term, then the second, and so on. If you don't want that then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-fields Or you can use key=lambda x:x[0]

Comment: "I think the bubble sort would be the wrong way to go." –Barack Obama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in sort method from Python.

```
import random
test_list = [[random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)] for i in range(10)]

print(test_list)

# sort using the first element
test_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
# or
test_list = sorted(test_list, key=lambda x: x[0])

print(test_list)
```

The sorting algorithm used for `sorted` is `Timsort`, which can achieve `O(nlogn)` in worst case and `O(n)` in best case. It is faster than `O(n^2)` by bubble sort.

reference: [sorted](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort), [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Comment: thank you :) This is helpful actually. I've tried to use the build-in sort function but I forgot `x:` so I couldn't get it to work. By the way, do you know the difference between `sorted` and `list.sort` if there is any?

Comment: Glad you find that helpful! And yes, most actually prefer the built-in method `sorted()` over the list method `.sort()`, since `.sort()` modifies the original list, or in other word, "in-place" sort, while `sorted()` doesn't but simply return a sorted list. Plus, `sorted()` can be used on all iterable objects but `.sort()` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort's time complexity is O(n^2). The built-in `sort()` function in Python will automatically sort by the first element and it will sort in O(n log n) time, which is faster than O(n^2).

```
def bubble_sort(n, array):
  array.sort()
  return array
```

NOTE: This is not actually a bubble sort algorithm. I just maintained your function name for simplicity.

Comment: I don't think that would work because every item in the array is a two-item list instead of a word/integer. I can, however, add `key=lambda x:x[0]` to let it sort by the first item. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort() (O(NlogN))which is an adaptive algorithm based on merge and insertion sort in python also called Timsort but in C for arrays quicksort is the efficient method that has the same time complexity as Timsort.

Comment: Setting that quicksort has the same time complexity as Timsort is a bit of a simplification. It's true in the average case, but not the best and worst cases.

Comment: I totally get what you are trying to say but you can refer here https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity