# on Python's "sorted" method being stable or not

Tags: python, sorting, stability

I am trying to sort a list array using the following code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data=[['Japan',0],['Japan',36],['Japan',21],['Germany',7]]
for line in data: print(line)
print('---')
sort1=sorted(data,key=itemgetter(0))
for line in sort1: print(line)
print('---')
sort1=sorted(sort1,key=itemgetter(1))
for line in sort1: print(line)
```

in Python 3.9.5 and I find it not to be working as I expect:

```
['Japan', 0]
['Japan', 36]
['Japan', 21]
['Germany', 7]
---
['Germany', 7]
['Japan', 0]
['Japan', 36]
['Japan', 21]
---
['Japan', 0]
['Germany', 7]
['Japan', 21]
['Japan', 36]
```

The first call to sorted did move "Germany" first without touching the rest;
but the second, that I expected to reorder the "Japan" lines by leaving "Germany"
on top, did not: it reordered everything instead on the second field.

I have been reading literature and answers all over the internet for hours,
found extremely many tutorials on how to do that, for example here at point 29: [Sorting a Python list by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212870/sorting-a-python-list-by-two-fields) and it seems that I am doing exactly the same thing. But clearly not.

Comment: You're not sorting by two fields, you're sorting by one field then re-sorting by a different field. If you only want to break ties with the second value, you don't need a custom key at all.

Comment: I agree of course. But the page I posted, and this one too:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html
promised me that by doing this I would have obtained a sort on 2 fields.
Since I am not, as the code semantics suggests, my question is:
how can I sort on 2 fields, with tie breaking?

Comment: What do you think stable means?

Comment: That after doing a sort on one field all records sharing same values of
other fields will remain in the same order

Comment: _"how can I sort on 2 fields, with tie breaking?"_ - in your case, because they're _already_ in the right order: `sorted(data)`. Or to follow what [the how-to suggests](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), as Python's sort is indeed stable, you need to do the **secondary sort _first_**: by the 1th value _then_ by the 0th value.

Comment: Stable sort will keep the same order _for items that are equal!_ [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5212940/843953) on your linked question doesn't work because your elements don't have equal items. Why did you ignore all the other (higher upvoted and accepted) answers

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe for the answer to "how can I do this". I had completely missed
that the order in the list was significant in the procedure. That is, one must first
reorder on field 1, and only then on field 0: this leaves previous ordering on field 1 
as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `sort()` or `sorted()`, it'll sort the list based on the key you provided it, and it'll keep ties in the same order it initially was. So, if you want to sort based on multiple parameters, sort it by the *last* tiebreaker *first*.

```py
['Japan', 0]
['Japan', 36]
['Japan', 21]
['Germany', 7]
---First sorting by the number (lower priority):
['Japan', 0]
['Germany', 7]
['Japan', 21]
['Japan', 36]
---Then sorting by the country (ties keep their order):
['Germany', 7]
['Japan', 0]
['Japan', 21]
['Japan', 36]
```